# How can I access my redux functions inside simple class and not a none react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to create a class to manage my api calls and I also need to access my redux functions inside my class, but beacause it's not a react component I cant use connect in that, I tryed to access my store directly but I dont know how to access my redux functions, Please help me with your advice.

thanks.

here is my code:

```
import { PixelRatio, Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {getInitUrl} from './ratio';
import store from './../../index';

class CallApi {

  constructor(userToken,userID){
    this.userToken = userToken;
    this.userID = userID;
  }

  _testSubClass = (names) => {
    console.log('hello', names)
  }

}

export default CallApi ;
```

Comment: By 'redux functions' do you mean actions? If that's what you mean, you can always import them from the file where they're defined with an `import` statement

Comment: Yes exactly. I have "CHANGE_VOLUME" as an action, could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch an action from any where using the `store.dispatch()` method.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example how to use it? I have "CHANGE_VOLUME" as an action.Type.
how can I access to that and also send payload?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about recently launched Hooks? It makes exactly what you've asked possible. It eliminates the need for a class component / connect() function in order to have access to the store. Check the redux doc about using Hooks with it!

https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks

Comment: Thanks, I read about that before, But I think in hooks I always need to return a view or something like react component, Can you please show me how to convert my current class into a hook and also accessing my redux actions like "CHANGE_VOLUME" in that?